# Run PLSQL external script with Liquibase

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, liquibase

im using Liquibase to manage my database in SQLdeveloper. Now, we have a PLSQL script that runs fine by itself. It also makes the changes in the database. Now, if we want Liquibase to run this PLSQL script it gets the following error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option.

Is it even possible for Liquibase to run external PLSQL scripts?

Comment: Please show us the code of the stored procedure

Comment: To answer your question very succinctly, yes, Liquibase can run external PLSQL. One thing to be aware of - your terminology is a bit off. There is no database "SQLdeveloper". SQLdeveloper is just Oracle's user interface for managing Oracle databases. As you are seeing now, there are many ways to manage Oracle databases. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "It also makes the changes in SQLdeveloper."

Comment: Yes you are right, I mean that it makes the changes in the database

Answer (score 4):

There are two potential issues you are running into:

1. You are using `<sqlFile>` but not specifying `splitStatements="false"`. By default, Liquibase will split the SQL on semicolons because that is what the JDBC driver needs normally, but in a PL/SQL script you can have a single CREATE PROCEDURE or something similar which contains semicolons but is still one statement. You can also use `<createProcedure>` instead of sqlFile which does not split statements.
2. Your script has sqlplus-specific functionality in it. SQLPlus and SQLDeveloper do not simply pass the SQL strings straight through to the database, they have their own functionality to sometimes modify what is actually executed. JDBC and therefore Liquibase does not have all the same functionality and so if you are using it in your scripts they will not work. If this is the case, the best approach is to use a changeSet with `<executeCommand>` to make a call to sqldeveloper or sqlplus.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser! I'm working on it now, hope it will help

Comment: I am using the <sqlFile> indeed. I changed the splitStatements to "false" like you said, but I still get the ORA-00922. in our plsql script (i can't paste it here) we do use "if" & "elseif" so there are some semicolons in the script. It is still posible to run this script without the use of <executecommand>?

Comment: ORA-00922 is a fairly generic response on its own. Is it giving any details to help point to the part of the script that is the problem. You should be able to use sqlFile as long as you aren't using sqlplus specific features but besides bind variables I don't have a great list of those off hand.